# Why did Imran Khan avoid the most obvious answer?

Tags: international-relations, india, pakistan

Watch the following video from 16:16 :

- [Pakistan's PM: Our economic future is now linked to China](https://youtu.be/-aTMY-aefjg?t=976)

The anchor asks the following question:

> Don't you see that Pakistan itself should understand that they can't continue as a country to see themselves as the victims forever? And, just I would give you a hint here. You have been trying to rally international support. The UNSC met three times about Kashmir. Absolutely no strong sign of solidarity with your country. All symbolic gestures. Don't you feel like you have been abandoned by western allies?

If I were the PM of Pakistan, the obvious answer that comes to my mind is as follows:

> Look Hashim, India has a 1.3 billion population. The size of the middle class is 250 million. This is the second biggest market after China. They are also the largest importer of defense products in the world. So, most of the powerful and economically developed countries in the world have a business interest in India. That is why they are reluctant to say anything obvious. Also, India is a close ally of the USA as they signed defense pacts and you know that. So, it should be clear and obvious why India is getting more support than us.
>
> But, we are doing what we can. And, we will continue to knock on the doors of .....

I have observed that this same question was asked by CNBC and the PM of Pakistan didn't say what I am saying here.

Why did Imran Khan avoid the most obvious answer?

What kind of damage does he think this obvious answer will invite in the area of Pakistan's international relations?

Comment: The title is vague and a leading question to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He actually says it [at 17:45](https://youtu.be/-aTMY-aefjg?t=1066) in that interview that "commercial interests" of a "huge market" (India) prevent [Western] countries from taking a stronger position against India.

Pakistan's Foreign Office [has protested](https://asia.nikkei.com/Politics/International-relations/Pakistan-alarmed-by-US-India-information-sharing-pact) the [latest] US-India agreement, but not an incredibly strong terms. I guess they have to straddle the line on that since Pakistan still needs/wants some US support and cooperation. And I guess it's for the same reason that Khan doesn't go on some kind of "America has betrayed us" rant on TV. Pakistan's former FM did take a stronger position and [used](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-pakistan-asif-idUSKBN1EU1QQ) the b-word in relation to the US suspending aid a couple of years back, even describing the US as “a friend who always betrays” on that occasion. Maybe that kind of rhetoric didn't help? In any case, both the US and Pakistan [struck](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2019/7/25/qa-was-pakistan-pm-imran-khans-visit-to-the-us-a-success) a more restrained [and even positive] tone around the time Khan visited the US, a year later.